# JasperServer and ttf-Fonts in exported pdf-documents

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, export, truetype, jasperserver

I'm running `JasperServer 4.5.0` and have problems with wrong ttf-fonts in the exported pdf-documents. I've installed the ttf fonts in the system and they are available in the jasperserver-preview, but if I start the pdf-exporter the document contains only the standard fonts (Helvetica or something like this). I do not get any error messages about missing fonts in the catalina-logfile.

Can anybody give me a hint what's going wrong?
Thank you in advance

Regards Adi

Comment: Did you use the styles and font extensions? Did you upload fonts to the repository?

Comment: I havn't upload the fonts into the repository because the ttf-fonts could be seen in the jasperserver preview (webinterface). It's installed as system fonts in /usr/share/fonts/...

Comment: I think you can try to deploy fonts or add jar file with `ttf font` (font extension generated with iReport) to the `WEB-INF\lib` folder

Comment: thank you very much for the very fast reply, will try it

Comment: sorry but nothing helped, the same problem as before, the preview is ok (with selected fonts), the exported pdf contains a standard font, no error messages at all. I've made a post in the jasperreports froum and hope it will help. However, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1) select the text field or static text element.

2) go to `properties` -> `advanced` and select the font you want in font name and pdf font name property.